# Disable TextField in J2ME

Tags: java-me, textfield, midp, lcdui

Is it possible to dynamically make `TextField` element disabled and enabled during the run time in Java ME?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to API documentation, [setConstraints(TextField.UNEDITABLE)](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/TextField.html#setConstraints%28int%29) could do something like that:

> Sets the input constraints of the TextField...

Note if you need to preserve contents and modifier flags, parameter passed to above method might require some tweaking, like

```
    setConstraints((getConstraints() & TextField.CONSTRAINT_MASK)
        | TextField.UNEDITABLE) // "disable" - set UNEDITABLE
```

above to disable, and to enable back, something like:

```
    setConstraints((getConstraints() & TextField.CONSTRAINT_MASK))
        // "enable" - cleans up TextField.UNEDITABLE
```

Comment: He asking about enable and disable the `TextField`. Not for Editable.

Comment: @bharath I understand. Here's what doc says about UNEDITABLE: _Indicates that editing is currently disallowed. When this flag is set, the implementation must prevent the user from changing the text contents of this object. The implementation should also provide a visual indication that the object's text cannot be edited..._ to me changing that flag sounds as close to enable/disable as it gets doesn't it?

Comment: @Sergey `setConstraints((getConstraints() & TextField.CONSTRAINT_MASK))` - cleans up TextField.UNEDITABLE => back to editable